# Convert the exact NSString value to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

This is my code.

```
NSString *dateString = @"2015-06-03 02:19:37";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];

NSLog(@"converted date = %@",[formatter dateFromString:dateString]);
```

The output of the code above is: "converted date = 2015-06-02 18:19:37 +0000". I know that this is because it converts the NSString with respect to GMT, but what i wanted to happen is NSDate must be 2015-06-03 02:19:37, same with dateString

Comment: So you say you understand why it's displaying the wrong time, but still state that the converted `NSDate` object is wrong.  You clearly don't understand why.  Please search as this is a very common issue.

Comment: You can change the timezone of your formatter.

Comment: @Droppy, i didn't say it is wrong, the converted NSDate object is correct however, what i want as the value of NSDate is 2015-06-03 02:19:37 not the converted NSString to NSDate.

Comment: Well you said "NSDate must be 2015-06-03 02:19:37" which implies the date object is wrong.  What you need to do is use the date formatter to format the dates (i.e. `NSDate` to `NSString`).

Answer (score 2):

> I know that this is because [the `NSDateFormatter`] converts the `NSString` with respect to GMT…

No, you're wrong. `NSDateFormatter` defaults to using your current time zone.

What you're not understanding is that "2015-06-02 18:19:37 +0000" ***is the same date and time*** as "2015-06-03 02:19:37" (in your local time zone, which must be GMT+0800).

Also, the description that you logged is just one representation of the date. The date does not have a year, month, day-of-month, hour, minute, second, or any of that. A date object just represents a moment in time. Such moments don't have any of that and neither do `NSDate` objects. Only *representations* of moments have those things, and they are only arrived at by processing the date through a specific calendar and time zone. In any case, any given date has multiple representations. Just because the description that gets logged happens to choose a representation that you weren't expecting doesn't mean the date is wrong.

You have implicitly requested a conversion from an `NSDate` object to a string when you logged it. That's because logging always involves strings. The string-formatting code used by `NSLog()` and the `%@` format specifier uses the `-description` method. You are never going to be able to force `NSDate`'s implementation of `-description` to use your time zone, so don't try.

If you really need a string representation (and you're not just debugging) and you want it in some specific time zone or otherwise want to dictate the format, don't rely on the `-description` method like you are. Instead, use a date formatter to convert from `NSDate` to an `NSString` explicitly, and configure the date formatter to produce the representation that you want.

But don't confuse the need to do that with the date being wrong.

---

> What I really wanted to do is to check if the given `NSDate` is already past 9PM EST (-4GMT), while i'm on +8GMT timezone.

So, use `NSCalendar`, `NSTimeZone`, and `NSDateComponents` to construct an `NSDate` for 9PM EST (on the current day, I suppose you mean) and then compare the dates.

```
NSDate* date = /* ... */;
NSCalendar* calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/New_York"];
NSDate* deadline = [calendar dateBySettingHour:21 minute:0 second:0 ofDate:date options:0];
if ([date compare:deadline] == NSOrderedDescending)
    /* date is after deadline */;
```

Here I used the convenience method `-dateBySettingHour:minute:second:ofDate:options:` and avoided direct use of `NSDateComponents`. If your needs differ, you might have to convert the date to date components using the calender, modify the components, convert them back to a date, and then compare.

Comment: i see, so i'll just create another instance of NSDate with a custom date, and not depending on the dateString since dateString if converted to NSDate returns the correct value (which is not what I want to get).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You don't want the "correct value"? What do you want? For what purpose will you be using the date object?

Comment: What I really wanted to do is to check if the given NSDate is already past 9PM EST (-4GMT), while i'm on +8GMT timezone. that's why i want to create an NSDate object that has the exact value of dateString so i can compare it to [NSDate date] accurately. Well, i don't want to hardcode the +8GMT because i can be anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Use the [NSDateComponents](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/index.html) class to build the date from the information in the string. The documentation explicitly provides an example of this:

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setDay:6];
[comps setMonth:5];
[comps setYear:2004];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
    initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];
[comps release];
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents =
    [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
int weekday = [weekdayComponents weekday];
```

Comment: How does that code convert a string to a date object?

Comment: `NSDateComponents` provides a `date` property. After you compose the date you can access the `date` property on your `NSDateComponents` object.

Comment: So how do you get the values from the original string?

Comment: @Droppy Parse the string.

Comment: ... to a `NSDate` object?

Comment: No to the individual components that you are interested in.

Answer (score -1):

call this method with your string value...

```
 - (NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)date
        {
            static NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;
            if (!dateFormatter)
            {
                dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
                [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
                [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
            }

            NSLog(@"Date: %@",date);

            return [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];
        }


    RESULT : Date: 2015-06-03 02:19:37
```

Comment: this returns nil, and by the way, the reason why you got the logged right is because you are logging the date not the [dateFormatter dateFromString:date].

Answer (score -2):

```
NSString *dateString = @"2015-06-03 02:19:37";     
NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
 NSDate *startDate = [f dateFromString:dateString];
```

You will get the NSDate here(startDate).... May this help to you.....